# Is there a way to initialize an object after it had already been declared

Tags: c++

In C++, I'm looking for a way to call a constructor after it had **already** been declared with a **specific** type, or something with similar behavior. The *code*:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Class1
{
    public:
        Class1()
        {
            
        }
}

class Class2 : public Class1
{
    
}

int main()
{
    //With this behavior:

    variant<Class1, Class2> object;

    Class1 object();

    Class2 object();
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it, why you even wanna do that?

Comment: Could you expand upon what you are looking for? (A single sentence is often inadequate.) Code should be an illustration, not the primary source of information. Especially code that does not do what you want it to do. (Not everyone is going to read your invented syntax and deduce the same semantics for it.)

Comment: One way to call a constructor in C++ is by using [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new).

Comment: For a few seconds i believed your question was about static constructor. Seeing the code, that"s not the case.  Each time a class is instanced directly or through new, its constructor is called. Even for a variant object. But i don't see why do you declare two member fonctions with Class1 object()  and Class2 object(). Was it a way to mean that you want a call to "initialization" for the Class1 object then for the Class2 object ?

Comment: As seen here, my goals are beyond your understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question is YES.

One can "re-initialize" the object:-

```
[...]
 Class1 Object;   //Instantiation of the object
 Object = Class1(); //Re-initialize
[...]
```

The challenge would be with the assignment operator.